# Python text template renderring

Tags: javascript, python, templates

I have an app implemented in Node.js having a function to render text template:

```js
function render(template, args) {
    // ...
}

render('${ foo.bar }, ${ baz }!', { foo: { bar: 'Hello' }, baz: 'World' });
// Hello, World!
```

In Node.js, I use a popular library [lodash.template](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#template) to achive this.

```js
lodash.template('${ foo.bar }, ${ baz }!')({ foo: { bar: 'Hello' }, baz: 'World' });
// Hello, World!
```

Now I need to **migrate this implemention to Python3**. I found a similar solution which using builin `string` module:

```py
from string import Template

Template('${foo}, ${bar}!').substitute({'foo': 'Hello', 'bar': 'World!'})
# Hello, World!

Template('${foo}, ${bar.baz}!').substitute({'foo': 'Hello', 'bar': { 'baz': 'World!' }})
# ValueError: Invalid placeholder in string
```

However, it seems like buildin python string.Template not support **dot to access dict sub property**.

There is many template alread saved in my database provided by user, so now I cannot update the sytax rule.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja2 template engine:

```py
import jinja2

t = jinja2.Environment(variable_start_string='${', variable_end_string='}').from_string('${foo}, ${bar.baz}!')
t.render(**{'foo': 'Hello', 'bar': {'baz': 'World'}})
# Hello, World!
```